# Commuting matrices up to a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is a problem I came across in my linear algebra research:

> Can someone provide two complex $ n \times n $ matrices $ A,B $ such that $ AB = \alpha BA $ where $ \alpha \neq 0 $ is a general nonzero scalar (meaning it can assume any nonzero value). In other words, the matrices commute up to a scalar.

Can someone please provide such an example or prove one doesn't exist and the rationale for the thinking process. Thanks to all helpers.

Comment: If $A$ is the identity matrix and $\alpha = 1$, any $B$ will work. Do you need $\alpha \ne 1$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a general nonzero scalar not necessarily one

Comment: @gt6989b edited question, thanks

Comment: Take $A$ and $B$ such that $AB = BA = 0$ and any $\alpha$ you wish.

Comment: As an observation, this demand yields identities such as $$(1-\alpha)\operatorname{tr}(AB)=0\\ (1-\alpha^n)\det A\det B=0$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: can you provide for a specific example of such matrices with $ AB=BA=0 $?

Comment: $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: thanks, now what if the matrices are invertible? Do you have a general scheme without the trick of product zero?

Comment: $\alpha = -1$, $\pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 1}$ and $\pmatrix{0  & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n \times n$ matrices with $AB = \alpha B A$.  Since $$\det(A)\det(B) = \det(AB) = \det(\alpha BA) = \alpha^n \det(A) \det(B)$$ $\alpha$ must be an $n$'th root of unity.  And this is possible: let $A$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1,\alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1}$ and $B$ the permutation matrix with entries $b_{ij} = 1$ if $j \equiv i+1 \mod n$, $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, if you allow $\alpha = -1$ is easy, as provided in Robert Israel's comment.

If you added the requirement that $|\alpha| > 1$ then the relation becomes impossible for invertible $A$ (or $B$) since
$$
AB = \alpha BA \implies ABA^{-1}= \alpha B \implies \det (ABA^{-1})=\alpha\det B \implies 
\det A \det B \frac1{\det A} = \alpha \det B \\
\det B = \alpha \det B 
$$
However, the problem did not specify that the matrices need to be invertible.

Comment: $\det(\alpha B) = \alpha^n \det(B)$, not $\alpha$.