# Finding eigenvalues of linear transformation given by matrix conjugation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and allow $A \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an invertible matrix. Define the linear transformation $$C_A: V \to V $$ by $M \mapsto AMA^{-1}$. Find the eigenvalues of $C_A$.

<s>The case is simple if $A$ is diagonizable. Since the inverse of any diagonal matrix is the reciprocal of the entries on the diagonal.</s>

<s>Assume $A$ is diagonizable. If we let $A = SDS^{-1}$, then we have $C_A(M) = C_{SDS^{-1}}(M) = (SDS^{-1})M(SDS^{-1})^{-1} = SDS^{-1}MSD^{-1}S = C_S(C_D(S^{-1}MS))$. Apply the fact about diagonal matrices to get see that this is equal to $C_S(S^{-1}MS) = SS^{-1}MSS^{-1} = M$.</s>

<s>So the only eigenvalue will be $\lambda = 1$.</s>

<s>How do answer this question for any invertible matrix? Since not every invertible matrix is diagonizable, it seems difficult.</s>

So my attempt did not work. Any hints on how to continue?

Comment: Let $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ and $M=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$. Then $AMA^{-1}=-M$.

Comment: $$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac12\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac12\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac12\\2&0\end{pmatrix}
$$ So $C_D$ is not necessarily the identity.

Comment: Starting with diagonal matrices is still a good idea.  Try writing out what $C_D(M)$ is explicitly in terms of the diagonal entries of $D$ and the entries of $M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a continuity argument to reduce to the case of diagonalizable matrices.  The characteristic polynomial of $C_A$ varies continuously with $A$, and diagonalizable matrices are dense in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (for instance, because every matrix is conjugate to an upper triangular one, and an upper triangular matrix can always be perturbed to a diagonalizable one by just making the diagonal entries distinct).

So, if you know the eigenvalues (with their multiplicities) of $C_A$ when $A$ is diagonal, you can deduce them for arbitrary $A$ by continuity.  In the case that $C_A$ is diagonal, you can write down what $C_A$ does to the entries of a matrix quite explicitly to find its eigenvalues.

More details on how to finish are hidden below.

> Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable with diagonal entries $a_1,\dots,a_n$.  Then $C_A$ multiplies the $ij$ entry of a matrix by $a_i^{-1}a_j$ (since left multiplication by $A$ multiplies the $j$th column by $a_j$ and right multiplication by $A^{-1}$ multiplies the $i$th row by $a_i^{-1}$).  In other words, with respect to the standard basis on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $C_A$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $a_i^{-1}a_j$.
>
>   Thus, if $A$ is any diagonalizable matrix, the eigenvalues of $C_A$ (with multiplicity) are $a_i^{-1}a_j$, where the $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  It follows by continuity that the same is true for arbitrary $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This post about [which matrices commute up to a scalar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180034/commuting-matrices-up-to-a-scalar) may be helpful, as you are looking for $M$ and $\lambda$ such that $AMA^{-1} = \lambda M$, essentially requiring $M$ and $A$ to change places and leave behind a scalar $\lambda$.